# str_replace does not work for some cases

Tags: php, str-replace

I use curl to get html and save it to $content. Then I try the str_replace, it doesn't work:

`echo str_replace('<a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications','OK',$content);`

But when I try to print $content and copy the source and save it to $content again, it works:

echo $content; Then I copy the printed and save it to $content again:

`$content='It is <a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications';`

With the new $content, the replacement above works.

Comment: It works for me - PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5

Comment: it works .. http://codepad.org/6SLzSaLW

Comment: Posting the question again won't change the fact that you have not demonstrated how to reproduce the issue. Unless we can reproduce it, we can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put '\"' also. I think it's a matter of this. I don't think the "style" tag has nothing that makes the difference.

Comment: thanx, sometimes is hard for me to think in english, when normally I think in spanish

Answer (score 0):

My guess is extra spaces or a newline or similar, try replacing chunks..
eg

```
str_replace('<a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" ','OK',$content);
str_replace('" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications','OK',$content);
```

and try and work out where it is failing, then you can track down why

Comment: And then you can use DOM manipulation instead of hacky, broken string replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$content='it is <a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications';
echo str_replace('<a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications','OK',$content);
```

So you probably have actual line feeds inside the strings and they aren't encoded in the same format, e.g., one is `\n` (Linux) and the other is `\r\n` (Windows). You can normalize both strings before comparing:

```
<?php
$content = strtr($content, array(
    "\r\n" => PHP_EOL,
    "\r" => PHP_EOL,
    "\n" => PHP_EOL,
));
```

In any case, PHP has excellent [functions to handle HTML](http://es.php.net/DOM). I would not recommend regular expressions for the task: they're unreliable and very hard to get *almost* right.

Comment: Please read my updated question. I doubt that the $content I got with curl is different with what I see with echo $content.

Comment: @user570494: Do you "see" it with "View Source" or from your browser's HTML output? You can't possibly analyse whitespace properly from HTML output.

Comment: @user570494 - When you print content, how do you see the exact line ending chars the text contains? Your updated question suggests that the problem is exactly the one I guessed.