# str_replace does not work properly for html content get from curl

Tags: php, str-replace

I use curl to get html and save it to $content. Then I try the str_replace, it doesn't work:

`echo str_replace('<a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications','OK',$content);`

But when I try to print $content and copy the source and save it to $content again, it works:

echo $content; Then I copy the printed and save it to $content again:

`$content='It is <a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');" style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications';`

With the new $content, the replacement above works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [str_replace does not work for some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646812/str-replace-does-not-work-for-some-cases) Again?? Why did you remove the problem description from the question? I said you should *clarify* it, not delete it. The only thing you changed compared to the (updated) original question is the title. Comment on the answers so the authors get notified that you made an update to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search string has an embeded return in it. This will have whatever line endings your PHP file has. Your curl content probably has different line endings. Try this:

```
$content = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $content);
echo str_replace('<a onclick="get_content(\'http://en.wikipedia.org\');"'."\n".'style="cursor: default;">Dojo</a> Applications','OK',$content);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Fore example, I highlight these html and save it to database. Then I fetch these html text from database and find them in the original html, it fails for complicated html like:

   `<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">JSONP</h1>
   <!-- /firstHeading -->
   <!-- bodyContent -->
   <div id="bodyContent">
    <!-- tagline -->
    <div id="siteSub">From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</div>
`